# Verifying user input by printing the input string back - C Programming

Tags: c, string, pointers, io, string-comparison

**So this is the objective -**

Ask the user to enter one of the letters ‘T, ‘E’ or ‘A’. Based on the input letter, your program must print the corresponding letter.  If any other letter is typed print an error message. Write a C code for the described task.

And my **code is down below:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

  int i=0; 
  for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

    char choice; /* variable "choice" declared */

    printf("Choose any letter from the following ('T', 'E' or 'A') : "); 
    scanf("%c", &choice);

    if (choice == "T"){
      printf("Your character of choice is ");
    }

    else if (choice == "E"){
      printf("Your character of choice is 'E'. ");
    }

    else if (choice == "A"){
      printf("Your character of choice is 'A'. ");
    }

    else {
      printf( "ERROR :/ Please choose from the restricted letters .ie. T/E/A ");
    }

  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output I'm getting is:

```
Choose any letter from the following ('T', 'E' or 'A') : E
ERROR :/ Please choose from the restricted letters .ie. T/E/A Choose any letter from the following ('T', 'E' or 'A') : ERROR :/ Please choose from the restricted letters .ie. T/E/A Choose any letter from the following ('T', 'E' or 'A') :
```

The error I believe is ***String Comparison* at line 8, 11 and 14.**

Please can anyone nudge this code in right direction?
Thanks.
**PS - I do not want to use strcmp() from string.h**

Comment: `choice == "T"` You compare a single character with the address of a string literal. That will never match. For single characters, use single quotes: `choice == ' T'`

Comment: You can't use double quote instead use single quote to perform comparison between char.

Comment: Didn't you got warnings when compiling your program through any compiler.

Comment: You also should change `scanf("%c", &choice);` to `scanf(" %c", &choice);`. Mind the leading space. Otherwise every other execution will scan the newline character you entered before. And also check return value of `scanf`.

Comment: @Gerhardh Double edged blade: That would ignore leading spaces as well, but *maybe* these need to be caught separately?

Comment: @Gerhardh do we have to put an extra space when receiving a string literal from the end user?

Comment: Thanks @Gerhardh for helping.

Comment: Thanks others for helping me.